# How to get IdToken while using Spring Oauth Resource Server

Tags: spring, spring-security, okta, spring-oauth2

My Spring Boot app functions as the backend for a Single Page Application (SPA). Authentication occurs within the SPA (using OAuth with PKCE via Okta), which then sends an `accessToken` to the backend. The backend successfully receives the `accessToken` in the header for authentication, and the current configuration appears as follows:

```
return http.httpBasic((AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable))
           .formLogin((AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable))
           .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
           .logout((AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable))
           .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
           .authorizeHttpRequests(it -> it.anyRequest().authenticated())
           .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
           .oauth2ResourceServer(it -> it.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
           .build();
```

However, now I need IdToken from this token in Spring app. How, do I get IdToken from this accessToken when I do this

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
// In this case authentication is instance of JwtAuthenticationToken.
```

Since I'm using Okta, I'm aware I can make API calls to the `userinfo` endpoint using the `accessToken`. However, I'm curious if there's another way to accomplish this in Spring Boot.

Comment: You should probably read [this Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2) I wrote: your SPA should be an OAuth2 client.

Answer (score 0):

You can't derive idToken from accessToken.

You SPA should request it from Okta (though this may be happening already) and then explicitly send it to your Spring Boot app.